# Flask Signing In and signing out

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-login

I am have created a sign in and sign out functionality to my Flask website. However, I am trying to hide the sign out button(on my navbar) when I am not signed in and show the sign-out button when I signed in.

Here are my logout and login methods:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if (request.form['username'] != 'admin') \
                or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You were logged in.')
            return redirect(url_for('availability'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)


@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged out.')
    return redirect(url_for('welcome'))
```

Here is my navbar for my website:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Student Support</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/aboutus">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/faqs">FAQ'S</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="/availability">Availability</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Quiz">Quiz</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    {% if 'session['logged_in'] == True %}
                    <li><a href="/logout">Logout <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li><a href="/login">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!--/.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

As you can see I have tried to do an if statement so if 'session['logged_in'] == True % display the logout button but it ain't working.

Comment: 'session['logged_in'] is this right? Remove the quote before session.

Comment: @Bugbugbuggerbuggered you are a genius lool

Comment: @Bugbugbuggerbuggered thank you

Comment: LOL it was a typo. Nothing major. You just need an eye not even two of them.

Comment: @Bugbugbuggerbuggered loool ok

Answer (score 5):

There was a typo it should be:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    {% if session['logged_in'] == True %}
      <li><a href="/logout">Logout <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li><a href="/login">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```